# Why is "what" used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, what

Consider the sentence:

> So how can a computer think if it knows nothing of what it means to be a human being.

Initially I thought that because "of" in this sentence basically means "about" the latter part of the sentence is not a relative clause as it is not adding any additional information, therefore is the subject of the sentence and cannot use which. Furthermore, as the contents of "to be a human being" is not known, "what" is used opposed to something like "that".

However, upon further thinking I'm not sure if this is a relative clause or not as technically it is adding information to the sentence by specifying what the "nothing" the computer knows is. However, none of the resources I looked at concerning relative clauses used "what" in any example sentences.

In other words, I'd like to know why this sentence uses "what" and what type of clause/grammar this sentence is.

Comment: There are actually quite a few questions on this site discussing this use of "what" and what type of clause it introduces. If you search for "what" along with "fused relative" you'll find many of them.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Thank you so much! I was struggling to find further information but I think knowing the right term will help me with my search!

Comment: It's not a fused relative construction. "What it means to be a human being" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of the preposition "of". The meaning is "... it knows nothing of the answer to the question 'What does it mean to be a human being?'"

Comment: Note also that if it were a fused relative construction, "what it means to be a human being" would be noun phrase, not a clause.